# SyntaxError: invalid syntax with executable_path in ipython

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ipython

I am using selenium web driver for an assignment in Python. I am getting a syntax error. I am using google colab and Python 3.

Here is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome (r "C:\Users\Anisha\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
time.sleep(20)
```

I am getting error

```
File "<ipython-input-28-7654fa692ce2>", line 1
driver = webdriver.Chrome (r "C:\Users\Anisha\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help I am not getting where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to pass the location of the **chromedriver** binary in **Windows OS** you have to:

- While mentioning the *absolute location* of the **chromedriver** binary through the *Key* / *Value* pair of **executable_path** you have to add the binary extension as as well i.e. **`.exe`**.
- While mentioning the *absolute location* of the **chromedriver** binary you have to either use the single front slash i.e. **`\`** along with the raw **`r`** switch or you have to escape the back slash **`\\`**.
- Your effective line of code will be :

  - Either in this format:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Anisha\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
    ```
  - Or in this format:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Anisha\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Do not leave spaces between *raw string literals marker* and the string:

```
r "String" --> r"String"
```

Use

```
r"C:\Users\Anisha\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
```