# InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable error using GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I am having trouble with a selenium error related to a FireFox binary.

I added C:/Users/Mack/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/ to PATH using backslashes and rebooted. I downloaded what I thought is the correct file here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
I put the file in the directory connected to PATH.

**To remedy this:** I tried using two backslashes

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
```

which throws the same error

I tried using one backslash

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
```

which throws:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mack\Desktop\hacker-stories\Trends.py", line 32, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(**firefox_binary=binary**)
  File "C:\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

Code Test.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("C:/Users/Mack/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64/geckodriver.exe")
print(binary)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/Data")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

Any help understanding this error is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's a firefox binary.

Comment: As @arundeepchohan mentioned, your argument to `FirefoxBinary` looks off. Shouldn't that be a path to `firefox.exe` instead of the path to the geckodriver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528718/what-is-the-executable-path-in-google-colaboratory-for-geckodriver Here's an example of the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

...implies that the **binary** file which you have passed as an argument to `FirefoxBinary()` isn't a valid [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) executable.

You seem to have passed the absolute path of the **`geckodriver.exe`** as an argument to `FirefoxBinary()` which is causing the error.

---

### Solution

Instead of the `geckodriver.exe` you need to pass the absolute path of the **`firefox.exe`**. Moreover, `firefox_options` is deprecated now and you have to use **`options`** and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

options = Options()
options.binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/Data")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/Users/Mack/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64/geckodriver.exe', options=options)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908154/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-expected-browser-binary-location-but-unabl/64908883#64908883)
- [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000401/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/66000618#66000618)
- [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided using GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318382/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/65322308#65322308)

Answer (score 3):

**This is how I solved it in 2024**

Your selenium, firefox and geckodriver should all support each other and here are the compatible versions:

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

I downgraded the selenium from 4 to 3.11 and upgraded my firefox to version 120. My geckodriver was version 0.33.

Answer (score 2):

Change the binary to whatever firefox.exe you get and your executable path to your geckodriver.

```
options = Options()
binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/Data")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel")
options.binary = binary
driver = webdriver.Firefox(r'C:/Users/Mack/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64/geckodriver.exe',options=options)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when using Firefox Portable, the FirefoxPortable.exe file is not recognized, instead, when creating binary path, point to firefox.exe file found under "FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64" (in my case). The above is valid if your Gecko driver works - so the first few lines of output (before the exception) look something like this:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
1611580278948   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:18391
```

This issue appeared for me **after** the problem described here:
[Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950748)
thus, they are not the same issue - as presented in some stack comments.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium 4 `FirefoxBinary`is deprecated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

driver_path = f"{settings.BASE_DIR}/geckodriver"

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/lib/firefox"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(executable_path=driver_path), options=options)
```

This code works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I've installed firefox through `snap` on my Ubuntu and Selenium was unable to find it/work with it. I had to install Firefox through apt, which was not allowed by default on my Ubuntu. I had to follow this guide: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 and then the problem was resolved ✅

My use case was I had to run Firefox in headless mode on an ubuntu server machine.

Answer (score -1):

Your path to the exe looks incorrect.

"/" (slash) is something used often in unix like systems to represent directory structures.

Window uses a backslash.

Change the string to use **two** backslashes instead of a forward slash.

Comment: This does not work ... binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Users\Mack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")