# Can’t login with InstaPy

Tags: python, authentication, instapy

I am trying to use some bots on my Instagram page, but I can’t log in.

This is my code:

```
from instapy import InstaPy
session = InstaPy(username='' ,password='') 
session.login()
```

I’m getting this error:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

I have the latest version of Firefox.

Thank you!

Comment: Read stackoverflow guideline for posting code segment. It should be like this ```from instapy import InstaPy session = InstaPy(username='' ,password='') session.login()```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username='', password='')
session.login()
```

Make sure you are placing your login information for the Instagram account you are using into the username and password parameters as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i still getting the same error. SessionNotCreatedException: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

Comment: it is all fix PUT FIREFOX on the path in edit variables

Answer (score 2):

#### My Solution

```
    from instapy import InstaPy

    session = InstaPy(username="username", password="password", browser_executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
    session.login()
```

**Pass** *browser_executable_path = r"C:[Custom Location]"* in your Session instance.

Reinstalling Firefox did not work for me.

#### Explanation

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

That message implies that the GeckoDriver was unable to locate the Firefox binary *(firefox.exe)* while trying to initiate/spawn a new browsing context i.e. Firefox browser-session.

**Why?**
Probably for 1 of 2 reasons:

1. Firefox isn't installed in your system.
2. Firefox isn't installed in the default location within your system.

Normally, any Selenium project would take...

```
    options = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

...for a customized location passing the absolute path of the firefox binary through an Options() instance, but since InstaPy handles initializing the browser, you must pass this through the class attribute "browser_executable_path".

**TL;DR**: Adding the parameter browser_executable_path of the InstaPy class allowed me to pass the r"C:[Custom Firefox Location]" as the firefox location.

**References**

- https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/6070#issuecomment-815819613
- [InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable error using GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034859/invalidargumentexception-message-binary-is-not-a-firefox-executable-error-usin/64035303#64035303)
- [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000401/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/66000618#66000618)
- [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided using GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318382/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/65322308#65322308)