# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

When I try to create a Firefox instance in Selenium, I get the following error:

> Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

I'm running on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

How can I fix it?

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "key.py", line 10, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

Comment: run ">whereis firefox" command  and set that path in FirefoxOptions

Comment: You need `firefox` binary and `geckodriver` installed. Put them in your `$PATH`

Answer (score 19):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) was unable to locate the *firefox* binary while trying to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

---

### Reason

The probable reason for this error can be either of the following:

- *Firefox* isn't installed in your system.
- *Firefox* isn't installed in the default location within your system.

---

### Solution

The possible solutions are:

- If *Firefox* isn't installed in your system, you need to install it before executing your tests.
- If *Firefox* is installed at a customized location, you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *firefox* binary as follows through an `Options()` instance:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = r"C:/location/to/Firefox/Binary/firefox.exe"
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="C:/location/to/geckodriver.exe")
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable error using GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034859/invalidargumentexception-message-binary-is-not-a-firefox-executable-error-usin/64035303#64035303)
- [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000401/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/66000618#66000618)
- [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided using GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318382/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/65322308#65322308)

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me by passing **FirefoxBinary()** options.

Code below worked for me.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium import webdriver
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
```

The above code will surely work for everyone.