# Not able to lauch firefox using RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am getting below error when i try to launch the firefox browser from robot framework script.
Below is the error which i am getting.
Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue.
I have copied the geckodriver.exe under c:\python\scripts folder

```
========================================================================
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provi
ded, and no binary flag set on the command line
========================================================================
```

Robot script code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  ../PageObjects/Locators.py
Resource  ../Resources/loginKeywords.robot
#Resource  ../PageObjects/Locators.py
Suite Setup  Open my browser
Suite Teardown  close all browsers

*** Variables ***

#${url}  http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/
${username}  admin
${password}  admin
${browser}  firefox

*** Keywords ***

*** Test Cases ***
TestCase_001
  hello world
  Enter username  ${username}
  Enter Password  ${password}
  Click Submit
  sleep  5
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908154/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-expected-browser-binary-location-but-unabl

Comment: No am i am not using selenium + python,i am using robotframework selenium library..this does not solve the problem

Comment: Robot Framework is just a wrapper around Python, plus the error message is the same plus the problem might be in where you installed Firefox. Have you checked that FF binary is installed and in PATH?