# Python Scraping to extract names of vessels

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
from scrapy import Selector
import requests
url = 'http://lines.coscoshipping.com/home/Services/ship/0'
html = requests.get(url).content
sel = Selector(text = html)
sel.xpath('//tr/td[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/text()').extract()
```

'''Can anyone help with this scraping, and I just want to extract the names of each vessels. Many thanks in advance'''

Comment: What's wrong with it? You need to add more detail to your question

Comment: Looks like the data on that page is loaded using JavaScript. Try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of `requests` (which won't give you the dynamic content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should produce the results accordingly.

```
import requests

link = 'http://lines.coscoshipping.com/homeapi/ship/findShips.do?slots=0&language=1'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'http://lines.coscoshipping.com/home/Services/ship/0'
    r = s.get(link)
    for item in r.json()['data']['content']:
        print(item['shipNameCn'],item['shipNameEn'])
```

Output are like:

```
中海太平洋 CSCL PACIFIC OCEAN
中海印度洋 CSCL INDIAN OCEAN
中海大西洋 CSCL ATLANTIC OCEAN
中海之星 CSCL STAR
中海土星 CSCL SATURN
中海天王星 CSCL URANUS
中海水星 CSCL MERCURY
中海木星 CSCL JUPITER
中海金星 CSCL VENUS
中海火星 CSCL MARS
中海海王星 CSCL NEPTUNE
中海阿里山 JEBEL ALI
```

Answer (score 0):

## The problem:

Inspecting the HTML of your [shown URL](http://lines.coscoshipping.com/home/Services/ship/0), it appears that the page content is mostly loaded dynamically. You can use a tool that can run the JavaScript to generate the page content so you can then extract the relevant information.

The [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library won't do this for you. You can instead use the [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) library.

## Using Selenium:

Firstly, observe that the HTML for the vessel names looks like this:

```
<div data-v-5c859f2b="" class="names">
    <div data-v-5c859f2b="">中海太平洋</div>
    <div data-v-5c859f2b="">CSCL PACIFIC OCEAN</div>
</div>
```

The code below [`find_elements_by_class_name()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name) to extract the HTML tags with the class `names` (which is used for the the vessel names).

Then, [`find_elements_by_tag_name()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-tag-name) is used to find the child `div` tags, which contain the Chinese and English names.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import textwrap


url = 'http://lines.coscoshipping.com/home/Services/ship/0'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='YOUR PATH')  # or Chrome
driver.get(url)
for vessel in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('names'):
    chinese, english = vessel.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    print(textwrap.dedent(f'''
        Chinese: {chinese.text}
        English: {english.text}
    '''))
```

I've also used [`textwrap.dedent()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to prettify the output.

### Example output:

```
Chinese: 中海太平洋
English: CSCL PACIFIC OCEAN


Chinese: 中海印度洋
English: CSCL INDIAN OCEAN


Chinese: 中海大西洋
English: CSCL ATLANTIC OCEAN


Chinese: 中海之星
English: CSCL STAR

...
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path) about how to download a driver (either Chrome or Firefox) and add it to the `$PATH`.

## An alternative way:

Using [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines), we can extract the Chinese and English names of the vessels more succinctly from each of the `div`s:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import textwrap


url = 'http://lines.coscoshipping.com/home/Services/ship/0'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='YOUR PATH')  # or Chrome
driver.get(url)
for vessel in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('names'):
    chinese, english = vessel.text.splitlines()
    print(textwrap.dedent(f'''
        Chinese: {chinese}
        English: {english}
    '''))
```

This is a bit more presumptive, but often does work (as in this case).

Comment: Many thanks, I tried to use the chrome driver but there is still a minor problem in the decoding part below.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import textwrap

url = 'http://lines.coscoshipping.com/home/Services/ship/0'
driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path = 'C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
for vessel in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('names'):
    chinese, english = vessel.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    print(textwrap.dedent(f'''
        Chinese: {chinese.text}
        English: {english.text}
    '''))

Comment: The error is "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

Comment: This is due to the way you declared your `executable_path`. Its a simple fix (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca))

Comment: And I also tried the codes in firefox, and it showed the error again.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import textwrap

url = 'http://lines.coscoshipping.com/home/Services/ship/0'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
for vessel in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('names'):
    chinese, english = vessel.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    print(textwrap.dedent(f'''
        Chinese: {chinese.text}
        English: {english.text}
    '''))

Comment: It looks ok to me, except the URL is missing `http://` at the start. Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I have "http://" in my code. The error happened on line 5 "driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\geckodriver.exe')". And the error is "SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line". I put the geckodriver.exe on desktop and opened jupyter notebook through firefox

Comment: Either Firefox is not installed, or its not installed at the default location, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908154/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-expected-browser-binary-location-but-unabl) for resolution.

Comment: Many Thanks I'll try this way

Comment: And may I consult you about another question, since I really want to learn this method from you. You're an expert. Can I also extract the "year" column with the same method? The "year" column is just beside the "vessel" column.

Comment: Yes, you can extract anything on the page you like. But it seems there is also an [undocumented API](http://lines.coscoshipping.com/homeapi/ship/findShips.do?slots=0&language=1) the site uses internally as shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65999212/14722562), so you could also do it that way as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's really helpful