# WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal | How to run Selenium Firefox Geckodriver in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, google-colaboratory, geckodriver

Hey stackoverflow community, I would like to run selenium for python, with firefox geckodriver in google recolab. I've found a post regarding this topic recently in which there's an answer  by [@DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb) from a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553986/15163882 . Sadly the provided solution, no longer works and I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

this is the code from the stackoverflow answer, that's supposed to download and run geckodriver;

```py
# install firefox, geckodriver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!pip install selenium
!apt install firefox-geckodriver
!cp /usr/lib/geckodriver /usr/bin
!cp /usr/lib/firefox /usr/bin

from selenium import webdriver

binary = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = binary
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
browser.get('http://google.com/')
```

`!cp /usr/lib/geckodriver /usr/bin` results in error, there's no such file, the geckodriver is stored in `/usr/bin/geckodriver`. `!cp /usr/lib/firefox /usr/bin` doesn't work too, `/usr/lib/firefox` is a directory, not a file. Overall, the code fails with the exception: `Process unexpectedly closed with status signal`

here's the full error output:

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    172                 command_executor=executor,
    173                 desired_capabilities=capabilities,
--> 174                 keep_alive=True)
    175 
    176         # Selenium remote

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal
```

### Update #1

Here's my best try, it puts everything in all the paths needed:

```py
import sys,os
from os import system as o

!pip install selenium

def sudo_cmd(cmd):o('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % ('12345678', cmd))
sudo_cmd('apt-get update')

sudo_cmd('apt install firefox-geckodriver')
sudo_cmd('cp /usr/lib/geckodriver /usr/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/geckodriver')

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

But I still get the same Error.

Also I noticed that the geckodriver.log file outputs `src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7fa48e915160  Redirecting call to abort() to mozalloc_abort` before the setup code errors out.

The remote server is running on `Linux-4.19.112+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic`.

I would be happy if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got same error. After some experiments found this solution:

```py
!apt-get update
!pip install selenium
!apt install firefox-geckodriver
!cp /usr/lib/geckodriver /usr/bin
!cp /usr/lib/firefox /usr/bin

t = '''
from selenium import webdriver

binary = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = binary
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
browser.get('http://google.com/')
print(browser.page_source)

'''
with open("main.py", 'w') as file:
  file.write(t)

!sudo python3 main.py
```