# Selenium Python Google Colab www1 url not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

Selenium works for normal url starting with www like "www.nseindia.com" but doesn't work for "www1.nseindia.com". Any fix possible on google colab? Below is working code to replicate the problem.

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

url_nse = 'https://www1.nseindia.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url_nse)
```

Error:

```
TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
  (Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```

PS: headless chrome option required for running in google colab

Comment: This works for me with `webdriver.Firefox()`.

Comment: Thanks @PApostol trying firefox now

Comment: Why can't you use this `https://www.nseindia.com` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I am finally trying to access {'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm'} which is only present with www1

Comment: @PApostol have been trying to get executable path for firefox in google colab. I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528718/what-is-the-executable-path-in-google-colaboratory-for-geckodriver). Could you suggest how to run firefox in google colab? Understand the question is different from the asked one.

Comment: @PApostol seems from online discussions that firefox isn't compatible with google colab. Any other solution you could help with?

Comment: Maybe try `requests` if it can replace `selenium` for your needs.

Comment: @PApostol needed to click buttons, so using `selenium`