# WebDriverException: Message: 'SeleniumDrivers' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, permissionerror

So I have endeavoured to learn selenium and I am struggling already at Step1: installation. In particular, connecting browser.

Here is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

import os
os.chmod('C:/SeleniumDrivers', mode = 0o755)
os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/SeleniumDrivers"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'C:/SeleniumDrivers')
```

Here is the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'SeleniumDrivers' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
Output is truncated.
```

I am out of ideas
Selenium was supposed to open the Browser (from VSC)

You can see the two attemps in the code, using `os.environ["PATH"]` (1), or trying `os.chmod()` (as seen in another thread).

I suspected a local issue in administrator rights but using a folder placed somewhere led to same result.

I have also done the same process for Edge as browser. Again the result is the same.

Comment: the path should lead to the driver executable, not a folder.  You won't need to set the 'PATH' environment variable if you supply the executable path.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I had actually tried that - and got the same permission error.

Answer (score 0):

The key [`executable_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553986/7429447) should be supplied with the absolute path of the browser driver executable along with the extension (on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) systems `.exe`).

---

### Solution

Your effective line of code would be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'C:/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I cannot 100% pin down what the problem was, but this:

```
from chromedriver_py import binary_path

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
Service_object = Service(binary_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service_object)
driver.get("https://www.google.fr")
while(True):
    pass
```

and this:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager    
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:/SeleniumDrivers")
except:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https:google.com')
driver.find_element(by='class name', value='jstest').text
```

..Seemed to work. Also I changed chrome version but I can't tell if this was the issue.