# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service' ,in python script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

While trying out and setup up a new script, i got following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\luism\Downloads\********\******.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\luism\Downloads\********\******.py", line 167, in main
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(driver_path), options=chrome_options)
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

My code is following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import requests
import webbrowser
import random
import pytz
import time
import os
import keyboard
from colorama import Fore
from pystyle import Center, Colors, Colorate
import time

os.system(f"title Kichi779 - Spotify Streaming bot v1 ")

url = "https://github.com/Kichi779/Spotify-Streaming-Bot/"

def check_for_updates():
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kichi779/Spotify-Streaming-Bot/main/version.txt")
        remote_version = r.content.decode('utf-8').strip()
        local_version = open('version.txt', 'r').read().strip()
        if remote_version != local_version:
            print(Colors.red, Center.XCenter("A new version is available. Please download the latest version from GitHub"))
            time.sleep(2)
            webbrowser.open(url)
            return False
        return True
    except:
        return True

def print_announcement():
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kichi779/Spotify-Streaming-Bot/main/announcement.txt", headers={"Cache-Control": "no-cache"})
        announcement = r.content.decode('utf-8').strip()
        return announcement
    except:
        print("Could not retrieve announcement from GitHub.\n")

supported_timezones = pytz.all_timezones

def set_random_timezone(driver):
    random_timezone = random.choice(supported_timezones)
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setTimezoneOverride", {"timezoneId": random_timezone})

def set_fake_geolocation(driver, latitude, longitude):
    params = {
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
        "accuracy": 100
    }
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", params)

def main():
    if not check_for_updates():
        return
    announcement = print_announcement()
    print(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.white_to_green, Center.XCenter("""
           
                       ▄█   ▄█▄  ▄█    ▄████████    ▄█    █▄     ▄█  
                       ███ ▄███▀ ███   ███    ███   ███    ███   ███  
                       ███▐██▀   ███▌  ███    █▀    ███    ███   ███▌ 
                      ▄█████▀    ███▌  ███         ▄███▄▄▄▄███▄▄ ███▌ 
                     ▀▀█████▄    ███▌  ███        ▀▀███▀▀▀▀███▀  ███▌ 
                       ███▐██▄   ███   ███    █▄    ███    ███   ███  
                       ███ ▀███▄ ███   ███    ███   ███    ███   ███  
                       ███   ▀█▀ █▀    ████████▀    ███    █▀    █▀   
                       ▀                                             

    print("")
    print(Colors.red, Center.XCenter("ANNOUNCEMENT"))
    print(Colors.yellow, Center.XCenter(f"{announcement}"))
    print("")

    user_agents = [
    # Chrome (Windows)
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36",

    # Chrome (Mac)
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_4_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36",

    # Firefox (Windows)
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",

    # Firefox (Mac)
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.4; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",

    # Safari (Mac)
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_4_0) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15",

    # Opera (Windows)
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36 OPR/80.0.4170.61",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36 OPR/80.0.4170.61",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36 OPR/80.0.4170.61"
    ]
    
    #FAKE Language
    supported_languages = [
    "en-US", "en-GB", "en-CA", "en-AU", "en-NZ", "fr-FR", "fr-CA", "fr-BE", "fr-CH", "fr-LU",
    "de-DE", "de-AT", "de-CH", "de-LU", "es-ES", "es-MX", "es-AR", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-PE",
    "it-IT", "it-CH", "ja-JP", "ko-KR", "pt-BR", "pt-PT", "ru-RU", "tr-TR", "nl-NL", "nl-BE",
    "sv-SE", "da-DK", "no-NO"
    ]

    chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
    driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'

    random_user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)

    with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as file:
        accounts = file.readlines()

    proxies = []

    use_proxy = input(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.green_to_blue, "Do you want to use proxies? (y/n):"))

    if use_proxy.lower() == 'y':
        print(Colors.red, Center.XCenter("The proxy system will be added after 50 stars. I continue to process without a proxy"))
        with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as file:
            proxies = file.readlines()
        time.sleep(3)

    spotify_song = input(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.green_to_blue, "Enter the Spotify song URL (e.g https://open.spotify.com/track/5hFkGfx038V0LhqI0Uff2J?si=bf290dcc9a994c36):"))

    drivers = []

    delay = random.uniform(2, 6)
    delay2 = random.uniform(5, 14)

    for account in accounts:

        random_language = random.choice(supported_languages)

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ["enable-automation", 'enable-logging'])
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,768")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US,en;q=0.9")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={random_user_agent}")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--lang={random_language}")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
            'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2
        })

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(driver_path), options=chrome_options)

        username, password = account.strip().split(':')

        try:
            driver.get("https://www.spotify.com/us/login/")

            username_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#login-username")
            password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#login-password")

            username_input.send_keys(username)
            password_input.send_keys(password)

            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='login-button']").click()

            time.sleep(delay)

            driver.get(spotify_song)

            driver.maximize_window()

            keyboard.press_and_release('esc')

            time.sleep(10)

            try:
                cookie = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept Cookies']")
                cookie.click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                try:
                    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'onetrust-close-btn-handler onetrust-close-btn-ui')]")
                    button.click()
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    time.sleep(delay2)

            playmusic_xpath = "(//button[@data-testid='play-button']//span)[3]"
            playmusic = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, playmusic_xpath)
            playmusic.click()

            time.sleep(1)

            print(Colors.green, "Username: {} - Listening process has started.".format(username))

        except Exception as e:
            print(Colors.red, "An error occurred in the bot system:", str(e))

        set_random_timezone(driver)
        
        # FAKE LOCATION
        latitude = random.uniform(-90, 90)
        longitude = random.uniform(-180, 180)
        set_fake_geolocation(driver, latitude, longitude)

        drivers.append(driver)

        time.sleep(5)

    print(Colors.blue, "Stream operations are completed. You can stop all transactions by closing the program.")

    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Versions of Software:
Chromedriver 115.0.5790.102
Chrome       115.0.5790.110
Selenium     3.141.0

Also tried diffrent versions of chrome and chromedriver.

Thats the Code i have, i relative new to coding, so i dont understand exactly the errors of the code.

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: @JohnGordon Selenium 3.141.0

Comment: I believe is it because you are using an older version of Selenium that does not know about the `service` argument.

Comment: @JohnGordon ok, so i have to update Selenium. What was the command to update?

Comment: The usual command is `pip install --upgrade selenium`  But your specific command may be different, depending on how you installed selenium originally.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword [**`Service`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) was introduced in [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4)

Till the last version of [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) i.e. [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v3.141.0*** the keyword [***`executable_path`***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553986/7429447) was in practice.

### This use case

There are two approaches to solve the issue as follows:

1. As you are using *Selenium v3.141.0* update your code to fulfill the *Selenium v3.x* style as follows:

   ```
   driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
   chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ["enable-automation", 'enable-logging'])
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
   chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,768")
   chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US,en;q=0.9")
   chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
   chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={random_user_agent}")
   chrome_options.add_argument(f"--lang={random_language}")
   chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
   chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2
   })
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options)
   ```
2. Update *Selenium* version to the latest *Selenium v4.11.0* release using the command:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade selenium
   ```